GeoServer Tomcat 302 redirect loop or 500 error after attempted upgrade
I'm upgrading a dev instance of Geoserver 2.22.2 to 2.25.2 which is running under Tomcat 9. I can only reach the instance via HTTP.
If I leave the default <session-config> in place in my webapp's WEB-INF/web.xml, I get endless 302 redirects between /geoserver/web/ and /geoserver/web/?0, because the JSESSIONID cookie cannot be set insecurely (I think).
Commenting out session-config completely in 2.24.4 allowed me to log in, but doing so in 2.25.2 gives me this 500 error (because JSESSIONID is prefixed by a semicolon in the querystring, presumably):
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
    org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlocklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:535)
    org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:505)
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(GeoServerHttpFirewall.java:41)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:100)
    org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

I've tried tweaking session-config, only commenting out cookie-config, but leaving in place <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode> - back to the 302 loop.
Am I missing a piece of the puzzle to be able to log into web admin over HTTP, not HTTPS?

It turns out this has been reported as an issue in the Geoserver tracker:
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-11326
I am on Tomcat 9.0.58, so an upgrade might fix the problem. That's not an option in my case, so an SSH tunnel to the box to make use of localhost exceptions to secure cookie directives is the only way I could avoid the problem.
